# Create a mesh from a simple contour in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I would like to do a mesh (triangulate) out of this contour:

[image: simple contour]

Is there a simple way to do it with opencv?
I've seen [Planar Subdivisions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/legacy/doc/planar_subdivisions.html?highlight=voronoi#cv.CalcSubdivVoronoi2D) but I'm afraid this won't do the trick.

This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272993/how-to-make-regular-shaped-triangular-mesh-in-opencv).

UPDATE:
This is what I want to get: http://www.spta.de/?p=220 it's done with openframeworks (which is what I'm using) but is there a way to do it directly with opencv?

Comment: What criteria are you thinking of using to create the polygons, i.e. the mesh elements? Or do you just want to fill the contour up with equilateral/almost equilateral triangles? Because the two links that you posted show two different things (haven't watched the full video). If you want to fill a 2D contour up with triangles and have it defined by points and lines I've done such things with Delaunay meshing. There must be something that implements this in C++ on the internet. If not you can do it yourself, it's not very difficult.